# Adapt JS countdown timer to show number of products left

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to adapt a working countdown timer we use to run a sale.

Instead of showing the time left in the sale, I want to show how many items remain available to purchase. That number should start at a given number -- say 1000 -- and decrease as the time left runs out. So if the number available starts at 1000, and the sale is set to last 4 days, I want the number available to be 500 after 2 days.

In the following code, I'm multiplying the initial "available' and multiplying it by the fraction formed by the "distance" (remaining time) over the "countDownDate" (end of the sale).

The "distance" should always be less than the "countDownDate" so that the number available is always going down as the time expires. But when I echo out the vars, it seems that the "distance" and "countDownDate" are varying widely and the resulting fraction is actuyally grater than 1 and making the number available higher than the original number.

Here's my code. What am I missing?

```
<script>
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Jul 01, 2022 20:59:59").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

// Get todays date and time
var now = new Date().getTime();

// Find the distance between now and the count down date
var distance = countDownDate - now;
var percentremains = (distance / countDownDate);
//percentremains = percentremains.toFixed(2);

// Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
var available = 1000;
var numbLeft = (available * percentremains * 10000);


// Display the result in the element with id="timer" and timer1
//document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
document.getElementById("available").innerHTML = available;
document.getElementById("distance").innerHTML = distance;
document.getElementById("now").innerHTML = now;
document.getElementById("countDownDate").innerHTML = countDownDate;
document.getElementById("numbLeft").innerHTML = numbLeft;




// If the count down is finished, write some text 
if (distance < 0) {
clearInterval(x);
document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "SOLD OUT";
}
}, 1000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This here:

```
var distance = countDownDate - now;
var percentremains = (distance / countDownDate);
```

doesn't make sense. The `distance` will be some number of milliseconds between now and when the sale ends. But the `countDownDate`, converted to a number, will be the unix timestamp of when the sale ends - something like `1656727199000`. If there are, say, 2 days between now and when the sale ends, the resulting calculation is `1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 2` (milliseconds) divided by `1656727199000`. But the number left should not depend on which exact timestamp it is. For example, in the year 2200, this calculation 2 days from the end of a sale would produce a far lower `percentremains`.

What you need is to add this in as a variable somewhere:

> and the sale is set to last 4 days

and then factor it into your calculations.

One possible approach is below. I've also taken the liberty of using more precise variable names.

```js
const saleStartTimestamp = new Date("Jun 27, 2022 20:59:59").getTime();
const saleEndTimestamp = new Date("Jul 01, 2022 20:59:59").getTime();

const timeoutId = setInterval(function() {
  const now = new Date().getTime();
  const millisecondsBetweenNowAndSaleEnd = saleEndTimestamp - now;
  const totalMillisecondsOfSale = saleEndTimestamp - saleStartTimestamp;
  const proportionOfSaleTimeLeft = millisecondsBetweenNowAndSaleEnd / totalMillisecondsOfSale;
  
  const productsAvailableAtStart = 1000;
  const productsLeft = Math.floor(proportionOfSaleTimeLeft * productsAvailableAtStart);
  console.log('productsLeft', productsLeft);

  // populate DOM, etc
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Excellent! As you said, what I was doing made no sense. I was comparing a timestamp to a number of milliseconds.  Thank you!